# onclick add image to div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to get image in a `<div>` using `onclick`.

Now I am getting the text on click. but I want to get the image in div on click...

How can i do this...?

Here is code I have implemented,,

Code:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML=images/aftersurprise.png;
}
</script>
```

When I click on element I should get the `aftersurprise.png` image on surprise element...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML="<img src='images/aftersurprise.png' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the image url to the `innerHTML` of div element. To add an image there you have to do something like this

```
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML="<img src='images/aftersurprise.png' />";
```

Or why are you not going with `jquery`, it's very easy with that like

```
$('#surprise').append("<img src='images/aftersurprise.png' />");
```

Comment: The difference between pure JavaScript and jQuery code here is negligible. How much heavier does your site get when using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Just giving the image url will not add the image inside the div.  You have to specify it using **`img`** tag.

or dynamically create it using the following code and append to the `div`

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'images/aftersurprise.png';
document.getElementById('surprise').appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById('surprise');
    oDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: images/aftersurprise.png');
    }, false);
})();
```

It sets the image as background image of the div

Answer (score 0):

```
img = document.createElement("img");

img.setAttribute('src','https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png');

document.getElementById("surprise").appendChild(img);
```

here u can set ur image src

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your issue is that all the content is displayed on a new/ existing page except image...! If that is so, you just need to put some delay when calling your JS function. Try this:

```
function Myfunction () 
{
    setTimeout(load, 1000); //this delay will allow browser to load complete image
    function load() 
    {
       var divToPrint = document.getElementById('surprise');
       var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank','width=1000, height=800, location=no, left=200px');
       //popupWin.document.open(); //needed when popup required
       popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
       popupWin.document.close();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divname').append or prepend("<img src='pathOfImages.jpg'/>");
```

here use only one attributes like append , another prepend >(before content)