# HTML image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking around for a solution to this problem but I am badly stuck. I am declaring  a div inside the html file to hold an image, and then dynamically add the image path in Javascript. But no image shows. When I declare both the div and the image path, then the image shows, however, I would prefer no to go this route.

The html looks like this:

```
 <div id="left" class="photos"></div>
```

and the Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('left').src = "images/1001.jpg";
```

What might be the issue here? Might there be some underlying mechanism that I am not aware of?

Comment: I don't know if you can add an src attribute to an div, but did you tried a img tag instant?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331606/onclick-add-image-to-div) that should help you

Answer (score 5):

HTML needs `<img />` tags to display images.

```
<img id="left" class="photos" />
```

Comment: Not really. As @Dmitriy says, you can use `background-image` CSS property.

Comment: you can also give a background image to a specific div

Answer (score 3):

`<img>` tags have `'src'` attribute. `<div>` tags - don't. 
Either switch to `<img>`:

```
<img src='my/image.png' />
```

Or use CSS `background` property:

```
div {
   background-image:url('my/image.png');
   /* Div element won't adjust its size to contain an image, so width and
      height properties might be necessary, depending on your intentions. */
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just realised this myself.

Comment: It is important to set also the widht and height of the div container.

Comment: @adripanico, you're absolutely right. Unless this `div` has its own size calculation and they're intended to drop some kind of background texture underneath.

Comment: Additionally, you use the `img` tag, with no `src`, but set a `background-image`. This gives you the ability to use `background-size:cover` but still be semantic with an `img` tag.

Comment: Possibilities are endless, and all OP wanted is just to display an image on the page and change its source with some Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, you're trying to set the `src` attribute on a `div`. But you also said you wanted to dynamically add an image to that `div`?

```
function setImage(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('left');
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

//  if there are no images
    if(imgs.length===0) {
    //  create one
        var img = document.createElement('img');
    //  set the src
        img.setAttribute('src',url);
    //  put it in the div
        div.appendChild(div);
    }
//  otherwise
    else {
    //  set the src of the first image
        imgs[0].src = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use just javascript, can you use that function:

```
function showP(el,pic) {
    document.getElementById(el).style.background = 'url(' + pic + ')';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will take your suggestions on board.